# BigQuery - Error creating scheduled query: dq

Tags: google-bigquery

I integrated my Firestore solution with BigQuery. With every Firestore Insert/Update/Delete operation the Data gets transferred to BigQuery. I am trying to schedule a Query that runs daily and creates a view of the Firestore data.

Everytime no matter what Query I try to schedule I get the following error : "Error creating scheduled query: dq"

The queries I try to schedule, run perfectly from the editor and I am able successfully to insert the data with an insert statement into the destination table. I am also the owner of the project so I am supposed to have all permission rights.

I appreciate your help!

Example Query Below:
"select
table1.column1,
table1.column2
from `projectid.datasetID.exampletable` table1"

Schedule Configuration below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QBYIw.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sC5Xu.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QeFdH.png)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and was able to resolve by trying a different browser ( chrome) and then leaving the Data location region as default in the New schedules query menu.